# AWS Sagemaker throws error "IllegalLocationConstraintException"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Currently I am trying to run the following piece of python code:

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import json
import boto3

sess = sagemaker.Session()
role = get_execution_role()

bucket = "mastering-ml-aws"

prefix = "chapter2/blazingtext"

from os.path import expanduser

SRC_PATH = expanduser("~") + '/SageMaker/mastering-ml-on-aws/chapter2/'

with open(SRC_PATH + 'dem.txt', 'r') as file:
    dem_text = ["__label__0 " + line.strip('\n') for line in file]

with open(SRC_PATH + 'gop.txt', 'r') as file:
    gop_text = ["__label__1 " + line.strip('\n') for line in file]
    
corpus = dem_text + gop_text
    
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
corpus_train, corpus_test = train_test_split(corpus, test_size=0.25, random_state=42) 

corpus_train_txt = "\n".join(corpus_train)
corpus_test_txt = "\n".join(corpus_test)
with open('tweets.train', 'w') as file:
    file.write(corpus_train_txt)    
with open('tweets.test', 'w') as file:
    file.write(corpus_test_txt)    

train_path = prefix + '/train'
validation_path = prefix + '/validation'

sess.upload_data(path='tweets.train', bucket=bucket, key_prefix=train_path)
sess.upload_data(path='tweets.test', bucket=bucket, key_prefix=validation_path)

s3_train_data = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, train_path)
s3_validation_data = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, validation_path)
```

However I am receiving the following error (apparently it is in the `sess.upload_data(path='tweets.train', bucket=bucket, key_prefix=train_path)` part):

`Failed to upload tweets.train to mastering-ml-aws/chapter2/blazingtext/train/tweets.train: An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the PutObject operation: The ap-east-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.`

However I have already changed my current location to `us-east-1` but the error persist. I was wondering if anyone had the same problem and how to fix it

Comment: Can you verify the region that you are using by import boto3
region = boto3.Session().region_name  and checking value of region it i returning ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy it returns "us-east-1" but when I run the mentioned part of the code it still throwing the same error

Comment: Can you create s3 bucket with s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name, CreateBucketConfiguration={ 'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-1' })  in your script and see if it solves the issue?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I tried to run the commands you suggested but it took more than 30 min and didn't finish running the cell.

Comment: try changing region